# Can't find the reason for a build error on Assembly language program which converts a string Array into an integer array

Tags: arrays, assembly, masm, irvine32

I am creating a program which reads a list of integers seperated by a single space via console and printing the sum of all the integers. The main problem is extracting the integers from the string array into a signed integer array.

Some examples of input are "-20 30 5" (each integer is seperated by a single space) or " [space]-20 30 5 [space]" (there may be spaces between the beginning and the end of the list, but the numbers are still seperated by a single space)

Also, after printing the sum, the program returns to reading another input unless only the enter key is typed.

After writing the code and pressing the Debug button, I am getting these two following build errors:

A2005  symbol redefinition: InBuffer

A2111  conflicting parameter definition

I've checked the error messages and apparently both of them are related to the PROTO and PROC directives. But there seems to be no problems regarding the parameter definition.

Here is my code.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

ArrayGet PROTO,                                         ; convert string array into int array
    inBuffer: PTR BYTE,
    inBufferN: DWORD,
    intArray: PTR SDWORD

.data
   BUF_SIZE EQU 256
   inBuffer BYTE BUF_SIZE DUP(?)                        ; input buffer
   inBufferN DWORD ?                                    ; length of input
   intArray SDWORD BUF_SIZE/2 DUP(?)                    ; integer array for storing converted string
   intArrayN DWORD ?                                    ; number of integers
   prompt BYTE "Enter numbers(<ent> to exit) : ", 0
   bye BYTE "Bye!", 0

.code
main PROC
L1:
    mov  esi, 0
    mov  edx, OFFSET prompt
    call  WriteString
    mov  edx, OFFSET inBuffer
    mov  ecx, BUF_SIZE
    call ReadString
    cmp  inBuffer[0], 0ah
    je  L3                                              ; only typing <ent> ends the program
    mov  inBufferN, eax
    mov  ecx, inBufferN
SpaceCheck:                                             ; calls procedure when it finds a number
    cmp  inBuffer[esi], 20h
    jne  L2
    inc  esi
    loop SpaceCheck
    jmp  L1
L2:
    INVOKE  ArrayGet, ADDR inBuffer, inBufferN, ADDR intArray           ; put inBuffer offset on edx, inBufferN on ecx
    mov  intArrayN, eax
    mov  ecx, intArrayN
    mov  eax, 0
    mov  esi, OFFSET intArray
Ladd:                                                   ; adding the integer array
    add  eax, [esi]
    inc  esi
    loop  Ladd
    call  WriteInt
    call CRLF
    jmp  L1
L3:
    mov  edx, OFFSET bye                                                
    call WriteString
   exit
main ENDP

; procedure definition

ArrayGet PROC USES edx ecx,
    inBuffer : PTR BYTE,
    inBufferN: DWORD,
    intArray: PTR SDWORD

LOCAL ArrayNum: DWORD
    mov  ArrayNum, 0
    mov  ecx, inBufferN
    sub  ecx, esi                                       ; ecx(loop count) from first char to the end
LOOP1:
    lea  edx, inBuffer
    add  edx, esi                                       ; edx points the offset of first char                                   
    mov  edi, esi                                       ; save location of first char
LOOP2:                                                  ; check spaces between integers
    cmp  inBuffer[esi], 20h
    je  getNum
    inc  esi
    loop  LOOP2
    jmp  getNum                                         ; jump to getNum if array ends with a number

getNum:                                                 ; converting char into int
    push  ecx
    inc  esi
    cmp  inBuffer[esi], 20h                                     ; two spaces in a row is considered as no more numbers afterwards
    je  EndBuffer
    dec  esi
    mov  ecx, esi
    sub  ecx, edi                                               ; length of single number in char
    call  ParseInteger32                                        
    mov  edi, ArrayNum
    mov  intArray[edi], eax
    inc  ArrayNum
    inc  esi
    pop  ecx
    loop  LOOP1
    jmp  EndBuffer                                      ; end procedure when loop is over
EndBuffer:
    mov  eax, ArrayNum
    inc  eax
    ret
ArrayGet ENDP

END main
```

In case you have questions about my intentions in the code or about the form of the input, feel free to leave it at the comment section

Comment: Your `inBuffer: PTR BYTE` function arg has the same name as `inBuffer BYTE BUF_SIZE DUP(?)` in `.data`.  Clearly from the "symbol redefinition: InBuffer" error, MASM doesn't allow shadowing global vars that way, unlike C.  You could make a much smaller [mcve] of just the problem of using the same name for a function param as for a global, basically just the `.data` section and the `proc` directive, as long as it still produces that error message.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I thought using the same name meant using the same arg, but apparently I was mistaken. I've been trying for the last 5 days trying to find out the error and you really helped me out, I sincerely thank you.

Comment: The stuff in `.data` is global / static vars, not local function args.  That's why it's getting declared there, rather than in anything associated with a proto or proc.  If you want to write a function that just uses global vars, it's not an arg (passed on the stack or in a register).